# Is there a string-collapse library function in python?

Tags: python, string, line-breaks

Is there a cross-platform library function that would collapse a multiline string into a single-line string with no repeating spaces?

I've come up with some snip below, but I wonder if there is a standard function which I could just import which is perhaps even optimized in C?

```
def collapse(input):
    import re
    rn = re.compile(r'(\r\n)+')
    r = re.compile(r'\r+')
    n = re.compile(r'\n+')
    s = re.compile(r'\ +')
    return s.sub(' ',n.sub(' ',r.sub(' ',rn.sub(' ',input))))
```

P.S. Thanks for good observations. `' '.join(input.split())` seems to be the winner as it actually runs faster about twice in my case compared to search-replace with a precompiled `r'\s+'` regex.

Comment: Why is "cross-platform" in the question title?  Almost everything in Python is cross-platform, except OS-specific stuff.  This clearly is not OS-specific, unless you've omitted something.

Comment: good point. I did not know that '\n' character is cross-platform in python. I thought that '\n' literally means a special ascii char.

Comment: It does literally mean a special ascii char. That character is the same on all platforms -- a newline.

Comment: in windows newline is \r\n on mac \r, sure \n is a new line, but looks like in python it will match all three. I haven't tested it myself though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The built-in `string.split()` method will split on runs of whitespace, so you can use that and then join the resulting list using spaces, like this:

```
' '.join(my_string.split())
```

Here's a complete test script:

```
TEST = """This
is        a test\twith a
  mix of\ttabs,     newlines and repeating
whitespace"""

print ' '.join(TEST.split())
# Prints:
# This is a test with a mix of tabs, newlines and repeating whitespace
```

Answer (score 4):

You had the right idea, you just needed to read the python manual a little more closely:

```
import re
somewhitespace = re.compile(r'\s+')
TEST = """This
is        a test\twith a
  mix of\ttabs,     newlines and repeating
whitespace"""

somewhitespace.sub(' ', TEST)

'This is a test with a mix of tabs, newlines and repeating whitespace'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
multi_line.replace('\n', '')
```

will do the job. `'\n'` is a universal end of line character in python.

Comment: thanks. good to know. but it won't work well since it will not insert empty space where needed and will not remove repeating empty spaces

Comment: I'm not sure what @Evgeny means by "empty space" but in any case the proposed solution doesn't address the OP's "no repeating spaces" requirement.